# Abstract Parametric Types in Julia

Tags: julia

Is it possible in Julia to have two structs with the same name but be assigned different types and thus be distinguishable?

I have been reading https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1 and it seems to be leading towards what I want but I can't get it to work...

In force-fields for molecular simulation there are dihedral parameters to describe torsion angles in molecules. There are different kinds for example purposes lets limit them to 2 kinds: proper and improper. I would like to have two structures, both called dihedral, but given the types "proper" and "improper". I would then have methods specific to each type to calculate the forces due to dihedrals. I think abstract parametric types get me the closest to what I want but I can't get them sorted...

```
abstract type proper end
abstract type improper end

struct Dihedral <: proper
    ai::Int64
    kparam::Vector{Float64}
end

struct Dihedral <: improper
    ai:Int64
    kparam::Float64
end
```

The above code does not work... I have tried using

```
abstract type dihedral end
abstract type proper <: dihedral end
abstract type improper <: dihedral end

struct Dihedral <: dihedral{proper}
...
end

struct Dihedral <: dihedral{improper}
...
end
```

But I always get in trouble for redefining `Dihedral`

```
ERROR: LoadError: invalid redefinition of constant Dihedral
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

My thought is that I can add in more types of dihedrals and all i need to do is also add in their methods and the simulation will automatically use the new dihedral.methods. If I try making structs of different names, then I start having to use if statements to direct the program to the correct structure and later to the correct methods... This is what I want to avoid i.e.,

```
if dihedraltype == "proper"
    struct_proper(...)
elseif dihedraltype =="improper"
    struct_improper() 
elseif dihedraltype == "newStyle"
    struct_newStyle()
end
```

using this method I would have to find all places in my code where I call dihedral and add in the new type... dihedral is just an example, there are many "phenomenas" that have different methods for calculating the phenomena.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the following approach if you want to use a parametric type:

```
abstract type DihedralType end

struct Proper <: DihedralType
    ai::Int64
    kparam::Vector{Float64}
end

struct Improper <: DihedralType
    ai::Int64
    kparam::Float64
end

struct Dihedral{T<:DihedralType}
    value::T
end

Dihedral(ai::Int64, kparam::Vector{Float64}) = Dihedral(Proper(ai, kparam))
Dihedral(ai::Int64, kparam::Float64) = Dihedral(Improper(ai, kparam))
```

and now you can write e.g.:

```
Dihedral(1, [1.0, 2.0])
Dihedral(1, 1.0)
```

The parameter of type `Dihedral` passes you information what kind of the object you are working with. Then some methods may be generic and call `Dihedral` e.g.:

```
julia> ai(d::Dihedral) = d.value.ai
ai (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ai(Dihedral(1, 1.0))
1

julia> ai(Dihedral(1, [1.0, 2.0]))
1

julia> kparam(d::Dihedral) = d.value.kparam
kparam (generic function with 1 method)

julia> kparam(Dihedral(1, 1.0))
1.0

julia> kparam(Dihedral(1, [1.0, 2.0]))
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
```

and some may be type parameter specific:

```
julia> len(d::Dihedral{Proper}) = length(kparam(d))
len (generic function with 1 method)

julia> len(Dihedral(1, [1.0, 2.0]))
2

julia> len(Dihedral(1, 1.0))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching len(::Dihedral{Improper})
Closest candidates are:
  len(::Dihedral{Proper}) at REPL[15]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Does this approach give you what you have expected?

**EDIT**

Actually maybe an even simpler approach may be enough for you (depending on the use case). Just define:

```
abstract type AbstractDihedral end

struct Proper <: AbstractDihedral
    ai::Int64
    kparam::Vector{Float64}
end

struct Improper <: AbstractDihedral
    ai::Int64
    kparam::Float64
end
```

and then implement methods in terms of `DihedralType` if they are generic for all dihedrals and if you want to add some specific method to a given concrete type just add this method with this concrete type in the signature. For example:

```
ai(d::AbstractDihedral) = d.ai
kparam(d::AbstractDihedral) = d.kparam
len(d::Proper) = length(d.kparam) # will not work for Improper
```

In this approach you do not need to use a parametric type. The difference is that in the parametric type approach you can extract out the parameters that are the same for all dihedrals to the "parent" struct and define only dihedral specific parameters in the "wrapped" struct. In the second approach you have define all fields every time for each struct.

Comment: I think that about nails it. It is a shame I got into Julia after the workshop in Toronto last week... Maybe next time haha.

Comment: It is very likely that a summer school on data science at Fields Institute will take place in Aug 19-30, 2019 where 50% of the material will be Julia (it is currently getting final approvals).

Comment: Would there be a difference in speed between using the parametric version or the simpler approach? There would not be many of these structures, but they would be used alot

Comment: If you use immutable structs (as in this example) this should be the same as the compiler should be able to optimize out both cases. However, if direct subtyping (the second approach - without parametric type) is enough for you I would recommend to use it as it is much simpler to write code and reason about.

Comment: I will go the parametric route. I will make more mistakes and it will keep me humble...